# Go to matching brace

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, aptana

What is the keyboard shortcut to go to the matching brace in PHP files?

I'm using Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.0.7.201112281312 standalone on Windows 7.

Thanks,
Shane.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a two-step process. First type the combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, then 3.

Comment: +1 for Ctrl-Shift-P although next I had to press 2 on my instance of Aptana 3